# Intellij build error: Execution failed for task ':classes' @NotNull instrumentation failed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-plugin, notnull

I use Intellij IDEA 2016.2.4 for developing a plugin. When execute the gradle task ("build" for example), I'm having the next error: `gradlew build --debug --stacktrace`

```
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: : @NotNull instrumentation failed for C:\Users\mri\ownCloud\dev\workspace\ca-aqe-livingdoc-intellij\build\classes\main\info\novatec\testit\livingdoc\intellij\common\I18nSupport. class: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This the class where the error occurs:

```
public class I18nSupport {

private static final String BUNDLE_PATH = "properties.locale";

@NonNls
private static final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_PATH);

private I18nSupport() {
    //Utility class
}

public static String getValue
        (@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_PATH) String key, Object... params) {

    String value = bundle.getString(key);
    if (params.length > 0) {
        return MessageFormat.format(value, params);
    }
    return value;
}
```

I've tried for unchecking "Add @NotNull  assertions" in Setting, but it doesn't work. Neither reinstalling Intellij or changing the pronject to oher path. I don't have further ideas :(

Also I copy and paste the stacktrace result:

```
13:29:55.189 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:instrumentIdeaExtensions] Adding @NotNull assertions to C:\Users\mri\ownCloud\dev\workspace\ca-aqe-livingdoc-intellij\build\classes\main\info\novatec\testit\living
doc\intellij\common\I18nSupport.class
13:29:55.190 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':classes'
13:29:55.190 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :classes FAILED
13:29:55.190 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :classes (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.637 secs.
13:29:55.190 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 3.037 secs, idle: 0.0 secs
13:29:55.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
13:29:55.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:29:55.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
13:29:55.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
13:29:55.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':classes'.
13:29:55.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > @NotNull instrumentation failed for C:\Users\mri\ownCloud\dev\workspace\ca-aqe-livingdoc-intellij\build\classes\main\info\novatec\testit\livingdoc\intellij\common\I18nSupport.class: java
.lang.NullPointerException
13:29:55.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
13:29:55.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':classes'.
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:68)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
13:29:55.198 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
13:29:55.199 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: : @NotNull instrumentation failed for C:\Users\mri\ownCloud\dev\workspace\ca-aqe-livingdoc-intellij\build\classes\main\info\novatec\testit\livingdoc\intellij\common\I18nSupport.
class: java.lang.NullPointerException
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.fireError(Javac2.java:524)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentNotNull(Javac2.java:476)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentNotNull(Javac2.java:480)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentNotNull(Javac2.java:480)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentNotNull(Javac2.java:480)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentNotNull(Javac2.java:480)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentNotNull(Javac2.java:480)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentNotNull(Javac2.java:480)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.compile(Javac2.java:255)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:936)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:78)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:93)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJInstrumentCodeAction.instrumentCode(IntelliJInstrumentCodeAction.groovy:75)
13:29:55.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJInstrumentCodeAction$_execute_closure2.doCall(IntelliJInstrumentCodeAction.groovy:44)
13:29:55.201 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJInstrumentCodeAction.execute(IntelliJInstrumentCodeAction.groovy:35)
13:29:55.201 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJInstrumentCodeAction.execute(IntelliJInstrumentCodeAction.groovy)
13:29:55.201 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
13:29:55.201 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
13:29:55.201 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
13:29:55.201 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
13:29:55.201 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 60 more
13:29:55.201 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
13:29:55.201 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
13:29:55.201 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
13:29:55.201 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
13:29:55.201 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 7.474 secs
```

Comment: Related issue in *JetBrains Support*: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/772795 and also in the issue tracker *YouTrack*: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161691.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it in the last release:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 EAP (build 163.5219.11), released on Sep 28, 2016
```